# Ошибка No source available for "__tmainCRTStartup() at 0x4013c1"

Tags: c, eclipse

я использую дебагер в Eclipse.
Операционная система Windows 7.
при использовании дебагера даже на простом коде он не выводит ничего и после выдает ошибку [No source available for "__tmainCRTStartup() at 0x4013c1"]
Я установил jdk, MinGW и указал их путь в Path.

Comment: Приведите свой простой код.

Comment: int main(){
    printf("Hello world")
}

Answer (score 0):

Пройдите в **Run -> Debug Configurations**. Выберите ваш проект кликнув на С/С++ Application.

Дальше выберите **main** в правой части и проверьте в текстовом окне под `C/C++ Application:` должно быть **Debug/(Название вашего проекта)**. Также, чуточку внизу в ***build configuration*** должна быть выбрана опция **Debug**.

Comment: проблема сохранилась